# I upload modifications to testflight and the testers do not see the changes

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, testflight

I have created an app and I have uploaded it to testflight the first versions all in order but they asked me for more changes and I have uploaded them and the internal tester of my app do not see the changes made, ie if you send them the message that there is a new version to download and they see the version number and they can download it but when testing it you do not see the changes it looks just as it was before. Any idea what it could be? I have searched for info and I can not find almost nothing. Thanks

Comment: most likely you submitted an old version to TF.  Be sure that you are doing a complete rebuild of the app before submitting

Comment: I solved it, I did two things, I did clean and rebuild the project and changed the provisioning profile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before as well. The only way I was able to solve it was to delete the bin/obj folders, close solution, clean, rebuild.

Then the next time the changes were shown.

I'm using Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio